# Can the typographical error question closure reason be slightly modified please?

Tags: discussion

Please consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28591478/34806), the answer lies in the difference between assigning with `=` and testing for equality with `==`.  Yet people seem loathe to close the question on "typographical" grounds.  Maybe the reason text needs to include something additional to the effect of "simple syntax errors"?

Thanks and now may the meta effect have the result of closing the question.

Comment: Regardless of the answer regarding dupes does the idea not have some merit?

Comment: You may be interested in reading [Now that "too localized" is gone, should we embrace the typo questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186181)

Answer (score 6):

Your premise/example for the proposed change is a bit lacking. This is a classic error that's bitten everyone who's ever typed more than a dozen lines in a language that uses `=` for assignment and `==` for equality testing.

It's more appropriate to close it as a dupe of an early, well-answered "if statement not working [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)" question than as "not reproducible", because there have been and will be multitudes of other people doing the *exact* same thing. This is, strictly, a "typo", but it's a typo literally (literally) identical to one that someone else will make. This isn't what that close reason was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this question is closed not because it's a typographical error (it is; but that's not always a reason to close), [but because it's not useful to anyone else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186196/16587).

It is possible for a question where the user misconstrued assignment for equality to be useful to others (even if it is a simple mistake):

- The question contains information another user would search for (exact error messages, specific well known programming terms (like equality, assignment, comparison; etc)
- The question is written in such a way that it is immediately apparent to a visitor what the issue the OP is having.  Not a lot (if any) "plz hlp me", but just the information we need, specifically the question should meet the criteria to stay open that this close reason lays out:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers.

If the question is a duplicate, it should be closed as such; if it's such a poor duplicate that it won't help anyone, downvote it; and after it goes into the negative, vote to delete it.